# Using for-in loop to find an object

Tags: javascript

I am working on some Javascript object exersice. I am stuck on using `for in` loop to find which model is the worst (highest number) and print the model. Here is what I have so far but it print all the model out which not correct.

```
var object = {"Camry":1,"Honda":2,"Ford":3,"Hyundai":10};
var count = "";
for (var prop in object) {
  if (object[prop] > count) { 
    count = object[prop];
  }
  console.log(prop);
}
```

The expected output is `"Hyundai"`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the value of `prop` in the loop, so for all properties the value will be printed.

You need to have another variable outside the loop which will store the value of the latest prop with max count

```
var object = {
    "Camry": 1,
    "Honda": 2,
    "Ford": 3,
    "Hyundai": 10
};
var count = 0,
    type;
for (var prop in object) {
    if (object[prop] > count) {
        count = object[prop];
        type = prop;
    }
}
console.log(type);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xujv1owh/)